# Perl, how to find a size of array in hash from json

Tags: arrays, json, perl

So, i have this example of json:

```
{
        "tab" : {
            "sort" : "true",
            "sort_by" : "0",
            "name" : "blablabla",
            "cols" : [
                "time_ep",
                "count_warning",
                "count_critical"
            ]
        }
    }
```

And after i decoded it into perl hash, i got a problem with "cols" array.
The `print Dumper ${$params->{$tab}}{cols}` looks like that

```
$VAR1 = [
          'time_ep',
          'count_warning',
          'count_critical'
        ];
```

I can't find the size of this array. When i'm trying to do that - it returns `1` or `ARRAY(adress)`, but when i try to get single elements of array like that:
`print Dumper ${$params->{$tab}}{cols}[1]` - i get what i need:

```
$VAR1 = 'count_warning';
```

I tried various options with refs, but nothing gave me what i need.
Any suggestions?

Comment: http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the size of `cols`:

```
print scalar @{$params->{tab}->{cols}};
```

You're retrieving an array reference from this key, dereferencing it to get an array and then using it in a scalar context - which returns the size of array.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $params = from_json(
   '{
        "tab" : {
            "sort" : "true",
            "sort_by" : "0",
            "name" : "blablabla",
            "cols" : [
                "time_ep",
                "count_warning",
                "count_critical"
            ]
        }
    }'
);

print Dumper $params;
print scalar @{ $params->{tab}->{cols} }
```

Note - `scalar` explicitly forces scalar context, but it will happen implicitly if you do 'scalar operations' like concatenation or numeric comparison. (`print` doesn't force scalar context)